# Visual Studio cannot include header file.

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Visual studio projects have a folder for header files. So, I put the header file in there thinking I would be able to type #include "SDL.h", but that didn't work. I did some searching for it and found nothing helpful.

[image: error]

Comment: You should perhaps enclose it with <>. Maybe you should also rescan your project.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Putting the header there only helps organize your files, it doesn't copy the file to the include directories nor makes it automatically visible.

You'll need to add the path to where `SDL.h` is located to your project additional include directories.

Just right-click on the project -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

In fact, you shouldn't have to add `SDL.h` to the solution, having the path in the Additional Include Directories is enough.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. Thanks for they help. Very easy to understand instructions.

Comment: how to open configuration properties ?, i am using ubuntu and there is a folder with many sub folders what do you mean by  right-click on the project?  @Luchian

Answer (score 3):

This folder view that you can see on the left is just project organisation hierarchy - it does not reflect your disk hierarchy and the actual location on the disk of your file can be totally different. And #include takes into account your disk location (and all the search paths set in the project properties)

So, to make short:
- Check if your SDL.h file is in a reachable location on disk :)